# Interface and List in c#

Tags: c#, generics

im having issues with the following interface and a class:

```
public interface IRelated
{

}

public class BaseItem:IRelated
{
      public string Name{get;set;}
      public List<IRelated> RelatedItems{get;set;}
}
```

Now when i try to do in other classes the following it gives me a compilation error:

```
List<IRelated> listofrelateditems=new List<BaseItem>();
```

> Cannot implicity convert type
>   `List<BaseItem>` to `List<IRelated>`

The reason of the interface is that in the future maybe i will have another class that can be Related to this BaseItem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like you yourself said: You may have another class that can be `IRelated`. How are you going to add an instance of such a class to a `List<BaseItem>`?

You will have to write:

```
List<IRelated> listofrelateditems = new List<IRelated>();
```

Answer (score 11):

You just can't do that - even the generic covariance in .NET 4 won't help you, because `List<T>` is a class and even `IList<T>` is invariant as it has `T` coming "in" as well as going out.

It's precisely *because* you might have a new implementation of `IRelated` in the future that you can't do that. Consider:

```
List<IRelated> listOfRelatedItems = new List<BaseItem>();
listOfRelatedItems.Add(new OtherRelatedItem());
```

where `OtherRelatedItem` implements `IRelated` but *doesn't* derive from `BaseItem`. Now you've got a `List<BaseItem>` which contains something other than a `BaseItem`! In other words, it breaks type safety.

Basically you'll have to create a `List<IRelated>` instead of a `List<BaseItem>`.

For more on generic variance and why it's sometimes applicable and sometimes not, go to the [NDC 2010 videos page](http://streaming.ndc2010.no/tcs/) and search for "variance" to find the video of a presentation I gave on the topic last year.

Answer (score 0):

Change to:

```
List<IRelated> listofrelateditems=new List<IRelated>();
```